# How to remove this type of stain from marble/stone floor?

Tags: floor, stone, stain, marble, stain-removal

In reference to the photo, these are stains I spotted when looking directly under light right beside my bath mat. Its also very close to my toilet. I'm not sure if there stains due to heavy water or possible urine stains. The floors weren't sealed.

When the lights aren't directly over, I can also see a hazy/foggy effect over the marble floor.

I tried just some standard marble/granite cleaner and scrubbed the floor in a circular motion with a sponge (soft side) but didn't do anything. Any suggestions on how I should go about removing this particular type of stain?

[image: marblefloor stain]

Comment: polish out......

Comment: Is it just a stain or is the surface actually pitted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it is made with micro abrasives [Nanoscrub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CFBJKCQ)  I use it on many tile projects. After looking at the pics again, I believe a sealer was applied to the tile and the "stain" is pitting in the sealer. I'd use the Nanoscrub and reseal.